# Hide title in Flutter SliverAppBar on scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I have a CustomScrollView with slivers that's working, but am not finding a way to fully hide the top portion of the SliverAppBar (i.e., on scroll, I want to hide the image and title, but show the bottom portion):

EDIT: As shown in the images, I want to keep the bottom of the SliverAppBar on scrolling. Setting "pinned: false" hides both on scroll, so won't work for me.

[image: expanded]

[image: collapsed]

Even before I added the padding, I wanted my title to hide on collapse, like this:

[image]

now that it's truncating, I'd really like to hide it.

I've seen posts where you can hide the title in a NestedScrollView (e.g., the above gif), but I'd like to keep my CustomScrollView if possible?

Here's my code:

```
class QuestionsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final questionsMgr = Provider.of<Questions>(context);
    final List<Question> questions = questionsMgr.questions;

    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
            child: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ScoreText(),
                    InstructionsText(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: questionsMgr.getScoreColor(),
          floating: false,
          expandedHeight: 225,
          pinned: true,
          title: Text(
            "Checklist",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          forceElevated: true,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            background: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/PalFM_blue.jpg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      floating: false,          
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
        child: AppBar(
```

Set the bottom property of the SliverAppBar to PreferredSize widget. Set the preferredSize property of this bottom widget to 0 (Size.fromHeight(0)), so that the sliver app bar's height will become the height for the app bar when the sliver is collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `SliverAppBar` to collapse, but the `bottom` remain visible, then you could do this:

---

To make the `SliverAppBar` expand / contract its content and prevent it from disappearing:

```
pinned: true
```

> The app bar can still expand and contract as the user scrolls, but it
>   will remain visible rather than being scrolled out of view. ([pinned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/pinned.html))

---

To make the content of the `SliverAppBar` appear / disappear when you scroll:

```
floating: true
```

> Whether the app bar should become visible as soon as the user scrolls
>   towards the app bar. ([floating](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/floating.html))

---

Then the PreferredSize of the `bottom` widget shouldn't be `0` but the actual height of the `bottom` widget.

```
preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60),
```

Comment: Yeah, but that also hides the "bottom" of the SliverAppBar. As shown in my image and the gif, I'd like to keep that. I'll update my OP.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts but "floating" only controls when the AppBar contracts, but it never contracts smaller than my image with the title chopped, regardless whether its true or false.  Thanks for the fromHeight suggestion. Stopped the title getting cutoff. (Obviously doesn't help toward hiding the title com.)

Comment: Did you apply these changes to the code of your question? Because it works for me.

Comment: Sorry. I misspoke. floating=true/pinned=true _almost_ works. Problem is I need the floating=false behavior of expanding AppBar only when the top of the list is reached. floating=true can expand AppBar anywhere in the list which which doesn't work for me.

Comment: i'm facing something similar, @buttonsrtoys have you found a solution ?

Comment: Not yet but I've been meaning to try Chijioke's suggestion that came thru recently. Did you try that?